# Warning when using package acronym: Hyper reference `acro:TPI' on page iv undefined

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

Using the package `acronym` to create a list of abbreviations at the beginning of my master's thesis I get a warning for each acronym: `Hyper reference acro:.. on page .. undefined`. This is quite annoying because it is difficult to see warnings that truely matter.

This is my code for the list of abbreviations which is then used as input in the main:

```
\chapter* {List of Abbreviations}
\label{chap:listofabbreviations}

%list of abbreviations and explanation
\begin{acronym}[SARS-CoV-2] % Give the longest label here so that the list is nicely aligned
\acro{COVID-19}{coronavirus disease 2019}
\acro{CPE}{cytopathic effect}
\acro{Cu}{copper}
\acro{DVS}{Dynamic Vapor Sorption}
\acro{E}{envelope protein}
\acro{FBS}{fetal bovine serum}
\acro{FTIR}{fourier transform infrared}
\acro{M}{membrane protein}
\acro{MEM}{minimum essential medium}
\acro{N}{nucleocapsid protein}
\acro{PAN}{polyacrylonitrile}
\acro{PA}{polyamide}
\acro{PBT}{polybutylene terephthalate}
\acro{PE}{polyethylene}
\acro{PET}{polyester}
\acro{PP}{polypropylene}
\acro{PRCV}{porcine respiratory coronavirus}
\acro{S}{Spike protein}
\acro{SARS-CoV-2}{severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2}
\acro{SS}{stainless steel}
\acro{ST}{swine testicle}
\acro{TCID}{tissue culture infective dose}
\acro{TPI}{threads per inch}
\acro{TPU}{thermoplastic polyurethane}
    

\end{acronym}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you use commands such as `\ac{CPE}` or somewhere in your document? If you do so, you should not get this particular warning. If you don not use `\ac{CPE}` for your first in text occurence of the term "cytopathic effect", you might want to use the `nohyperlinks` package option of the `acronym` package.

Comment: Indeed I am not using \ac{CPE} commands anywhere. I tried using \acs and \acl but this didn't remove the warning. I just tried using \ac and this indeed removes the warning although this also put's the full explanation and then the abbreviation between brackets. I didn't want to use this everywhere the first time an abbreviation is used but if it removes the warning I will do so.

Comment: If you explicitly don't want full and short form to appear the first time you use an acronym (how should the reader know what this acronym means if you don't also include the long form upon first use?), you could try the `nohyperref` option. This will however, also remove hyperlinks from `\acs` to the list of acronyms.

Comment: Sometimes these abbreviations are just short sample names used in tables and the full text wouldn't esthetically fit in the table. For the most in text abbreviations I do put the explanation first and then between brackets the abbreviation. But for example for COVID-19 I think at this point it's not necessary to put coronavirus disease 2019 in the text as everyone knows this by now and it is just so long. I might try the `nohyperlinks` option after all.